# map two columns in a file to another file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a big file `A` (tab delimited) with ~8 million of rows, the file looks like this:

```
1 10001
1 10005
1 10019
1 10055
1 10108
```

And another file `B` that looks like this:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO
1   10001   .   T   C   .   .   AF=0.0000384;AC=1;AN=26028;DS=SS6004475
1   10002   .   A   C,T .   .   AF=0.0001153,0.0000384;AC=3,1;AN=26028;DS=HGDP00927|HGDP00998|HGDP01284,HGDP01029
1   10002   .   A   AT  .   .   AF=0.0000384;AC=1;AN=26028;DS=HGDP00521
1   10003   .   A   C,T .   .   AF=0.0000384,0.0000768;AC=1,2;AN=26028;DS=HGDP01284,HGDP00521|HGDP00927
1   10004   .   C   A   .   .   AF=0.0000384;AC=1;AN=26028;DS=HGDP01284
1   10018   .   C   T   .   .   AF=0.0000384;AC=1;AN=26028;DS=HGDP00998
1   10019   rs775809821 TA  T   .   .   AF=0.0000384;AC=1;AN=26028;END=10020;DS=Malay
1   10055   rs768019142 T   TA  .   .   AF=0.0000384;AC=1;AN=26028;DS=Malay 
1   10108   rs62651026  C   T   .   .   AF=0.0000768;AC=2;AN=26028;DS=HGDP00778|HGDP0456
```

What I want is to match the columns in the file `A` with the first two columns of file `B` and add info from the 3rd column of file `B` to file `A`. If there is no match I would like to output a `NA` instead. The desired output would be something like this. The `B` file also have several commented lines with `#` that I would like to avoid while reading the file. The output would be something like this:

```
1 10001 .
1 10005 NA
1 10019 rs775809821
1 10055 rs768019142
1 10108 rs62651026
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write something like

```
awk 'NR==FNR{line[$1" "$2]=$3; next} ($0 in line){print $0,line[$0]; next} {print $0, "NA"}' file2 file1
```

**Example**

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{line[$1" "$2]=$3; next} ($0 in line){print $0,line[$0]; next} {print $0, "NA"}' file2 file1
1 10001 .
1 10005 NA
1 10019 rs775809821
1 10055 rs768019142
1 10108 rs62651026
```

**What it does?**

- `NR==FNR{line[$1" "$2]=$3; next}` If the input file is first file ( which is taken care by `NR==FNR` ), then we save the `$3` in array `line` indexed by `$1" "$2`.
- `($0 in line){print $0,line[$0]; next}` For the second file, if the current line is in `line` then print that line, followed by value in the `file2`.
- `{print $0, "NA"}` If not print the line followed by `NA`.

Comment: OP wants to associate based on the first *two* columns. Edited that. Good answer anyway! +1

Comment: @nu11p01n73R, what would happen if the file 2 is a `gz` file compress with `bgzip`, could it be done without uncompressing the file?

Answer (score 0):

Does your 1st column only contain numerical values? Would these contain more than 1-2 digits? Would you expect numbers greater than 5-9 digits in the 2nd column? Are both files numerically sorted (i.e. `sort -k1n,1 -k2n,2`)? Is the combination of columns 1 and 2 unique in each file (or do they contain duplicates)? If you can answer yes to all of the above questions, then here is another solution.

```
join -a1 -o 1.2,1.3,2.2 -e "NA" \
<(awk '{printf("%02d:%09d\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2, $1, $2)}' A) \
<(cat B | grep -v ^# | awk '{printf("%02d:%09d\t%s\n", $1, $2, $3)}')
```

If file `B` is gzipped, then just use `zcat B` or `gunzip -c B` instead of `cat B`.